# Observing data changes from parent to child or vice versa

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a service that I subscribe in the, let's say A component. I have a method in the A component that subscribes to the service every 5 minutes.

An A component has a child component let's say B component. I use @Input() and get the data in B component. Also, a B component has a child C component. C component displays the message. I need to get the data changes that happens after subscribing to the service every 5 minutes and get them in the B component which will invoke the C component.

I need the service call to happen in the A component since, there's some logic needs to be done there too. If the service call happens in B component and I'd like to know how to observe data changes in child.

1. I tried using timer, pipe and switchMap to avoid using an interval and make the service subscription happen every 5 minutes and call the service from both A and B components.
2. Also, I tried using ViewChild() and called the ngOnInit of B component in A component but that gives me an error :

   cannot read property ngOnInit() of undefined at SafeSubscriber...

but it would still invoke at subscription.

3. continuing the 2nd point, if I call the ngOnInit of C to B... I would get a cross origin policy error.
4. I tried subscribing the service in B component in a similar manner as A. and I tried to output the data changes to A. But, that doesn't seem to work either. If this is a better idea, would really like to know how to observe data changes from child.

Acomponent:

```
    ngOnInit() {
           this.method();
           this.interval = setInterval(()=>this.method(), 300000);
    }

    method() {
           // service subscription
    }


    ngOnDestroy(){
            clearInterval(this.interval);
    }
```

Acomponent.html:

```
    <Bcomponent [data]='data'></BComponent>
```

BComponent:

```
      @Input() data: any;

      ngOnInit() {
               this.method(); 
      }

      method() {
             // method to be executed
      }
```

BComponent.html:

```
       <Ccomponent [datafromBmethod]='datafromBmethod'></Ccomponent>
```

Ccomponent:

```
      @input() datafromBmethod: any;

      ngOnInit() {
               // display message logic
      }
```

Comment: So what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: the problem I'm facing is I can't see the data changes after subscription

Answer (score 0):

Karan, the thing are not as you asking. Yo need'nt susbcribe to a service each time. Imagine you has a service DataService with a method getData. If you want to get this data each x seconds you can susbcribe in onInit to a timer using switchMap. To unsusbcribe I use takeWhile a variable was true, that in ngOnDestroy becomes false

```
 timer(0,1000).pipe(takeWhile(()=>this.alive),
                  switchMap(()=>{
                    return this.dataService.getData()
                  })).subscribe(res=>{
                    this.value=res;
                  })
```

the variable "this.value" change each 1 secons. You can pass this variable to b using input, and pass the variable from b to c using input too.

NOTE: I use the operator "of" to return an observable, in general the service becomes like

```
  getData()
  {
    return this.httpClient.get(.....)
  }
```

You can also has a Subject in your service, in timer of app-component send a message and subscribe to the subject as observable is c

You component A becomes like

```
 timer(0,1000).pipe(takeWhile(()=>this.alive),
              switchMap(()=>{
                return this.dataService.getData()
              })).subscribe(res=>{
                this.dataService.putMessage("I send "+res);
              })
```

And in component c you has

```
this.dataService.dataObservable.subscribe(res=>{
   this.message=res;
})
```

You can see an example of both cases in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vk65cu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fb.component.ts)

Comment: okay I shall try that... the problem I'm facing is I can't see the data changes after subscription