# Angular setTimeout running too many times

Tags: javascript, angular, intervals

I have a log viewer component implemented in two or more other components. This log viewer uses a setTimeout to create an interval loop to fetch data from a file. My problem is since this component is imported in other components the timer runs for every component separately thus making multiple file reads per second.

Can this be avoided and run the timer only once regardless of the number of components using this component?

Here's the code for the log viewer component where the setTimeout interval is created:

```
import { Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { LogsService } from '../../services/logs.service';
import { HelperService } from '../../services/helper.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-logger',
    templateUrl: './logger.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./logger.component.scss']
})
export class LoggerComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild('scroller', {static: false}) scroller: ElementRef;

    logClassName: string = 'logs shadow close';
    logs: string = '';
    logTS: number = 0;
    logTimer;
    scrollTop: number = 0;

    constructor(
        private logsService: LogsService,
        private h: HelperService
    ){}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getLogs();
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        if (this.logTimer) window.clearTimeout(this.logTimer);
    }

    toggle(type){
        switch (type)
        {
            case 'open': this.logClassName = 'logs shadow open'; break;
            case 'close': this.logClassName = 'logs shadow close'; break;
            case 'full': this.logClassName = 'logs shadow full'; break;
        }
    }

    getLogs(){
        this.logsService.fetch(this.logTS).subscribe(
            response => {
                this.logs += response.data.join('');
                this.logTS = response.ts;

                window.setTimeout(() => {
                    this.scrollTop = this.scroller.nativeElement.scrollHeight;
                }, 100);

                this.setLogTimer();
            },
            error => {
                this.h.lg('unable to fetch logs', 'error');
                this.logs = '<p>Unable to fetch logs</p>';

                this.setLogTimer();
            }
        );
    }

    setLogTimer(){
        if (this.logTimer) window.clearTimeout(this.logTimer);

        this.logTimer = window.setTimeout(() => {
            this.getLogs();
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `this.logTimer` is associated with component instance and it will be different for each instance and never get cancelled solution would be to use some shared service to perform your file read like

```
@Injectable(provideIn:'root')
export class SomeService{

    setLogTimer(){
            if (this.logTimer) window.clearTimeout(this.logTimer);

            this.logTimer = window.setTimeout(() => {
                this.getLogs();
            }, 1000);
        }

}
```

Then use this service in your component like

```
this.someService.setLogTimer()
```

Comment: Another aproach is create an observable using 'rxjs' timer, and subscribe/unsubscribe, see an example in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57337138/observing-data-changes-from-parent-to-child-or-vice-versa/57337576#57337576

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem Angular has [Singleton services](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services). You can move the `setLogTimer()` and `logTimer` in your `LogsService`.